# How to get current user id from facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, koala

How to get current user ID form facebook using koala gems?

```
 def UserDetailsfb

    @user_id = current_user.id.to_s
        utility = Utility.new
        par = Hash.new
        utility.request = par
        @fb_uid = Account.find_by_id(6)
        @fb_code = @fb_uid.auth_token    
        @fbuid = @fb_uid.uid       
        @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@fb_code)
        @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@fb_code)      
        tweet_array = []
        @response = @graph.get_object(id);
        render :json => { :tweetArray => @response }     
  end
```

i need to get the current user id. Showing error "undefined local variable or method `id' for #"

Comment: isn't the ID already in `@fb_uid.uid`?

Comment: has my answer been heplful?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error (semicolon) on this line:

```
    @response = @graph.get_object(id);
```

Additionally that line has an (presumably) undefined variable `id`. Maybe you copy/pasted it in?

You probably would be passing in `@fb_uid`, e.g.:

```
    @response = @graph.get_object(@fb_uid)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need simply get `id` of the user that has authenticated with facebook, just do request:

```
@profile = @graph.get_object 'me'
render :json => { :tweetArray => @profile }
```

This gets profile info for user that acquired the specified oauth token.

But I guess, you have used wrong variable name, I suppose the true id is keeping in the field `uid` of an Account record. So try just this:

```
@profile = @graph.get_object @fb_uid.uid
render :json => { :tweetArray => @profile }
```